# Disable/Convert Java making big number smaller? (1000,000,0000 to 1E10) using SPEL Expression

Tags: java, integer, number-formatting, spring-el, decimalformat

I'm extracting value 10000000000 using XPath from the xml message using Spring SPEL. However, it is being shown as 1E10 in scientific notation but I'd like to keep it in the same format (10000000000).

How can I achieve this using SPEL language expression?

#derivedValue = value extracted from XPath which is 10000000000

I tried using java DecimalFormat in the transformation rule like below but didn't work and throws spel exception:

> new java.text.DecimalFormat.getIntegerInstance().format((T(java.lang.Double)).parseDouble(#derivedValue)

Comment: @iota No. value is 10000000000 in xml..

Comment: @GaryRussell So Xpath is like "//foo/fooStream/fooPeriodAmount/fooCalc/Schedule/initialValue" where value is 10000000000.

Comment: @GaryRussell Here is the sample SPEL:  new java.text.DecimalFormat("#0.0000").format((T(java.lang.Double).parseDouble(#derivedValue)))..

Comment: So then you are getting it as a `double`.

Comment: See my answer; NUMBER_RESULT evaluation type returns a double; you don't show where `#derivedValue` is evaluated but if it's the result, it's a double, so `#derivedValue.longValue()` will convert it to a Long.

Answer (score 0):

Use `longValue()` on the `Double`.

Using Spring Integration's `#xpath` function like this works...

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(BeanFactory bf) {
    return args -> {
        Object value =
                new SpelExpressionParser()
                        .parseExpression("#xpath(#root, '/foo', 'number').longValue()")
                        .getValue(IntegrationContextUtils.getEvaluationContext(bf), "<foo>10000000000</foo>");
        System.out.println(value);
    };
}
```

Comment: Basically my goal is not to use any fancy spring bean code here but to achieve conversion/tag value as 10000000000 and not in scientific notation when xml message is published.

Comment: You said you were using XPath; I just happened to use the implementation I am familiar with. If you evaluate the Xpath using a `NUMBER_RESULT` evaluation type, you will get a `Double`; just call `longValue()` on it.